# How to add footer in page generated using Shiny Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have the following [**RMarkdown FlexDashboard**](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) document:

````
---
title: "Some title"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Some chart

```{r}
plot(faithful)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart 2

```{r}
```   

### Chart 3

```{r}
```
````

How can I put the footer that span across the page with the following content?

```
tags$div( HTML("<footer><small>&copy; Copyright 2017, MyCompany Co.,Ltd</small></footer>"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the HTML of your footer in a `footer.html` file and include it after the `body` of your flexdashboard using `after_body` in your markdown:

```
---
title: "Some title"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    includes:
      after_body: footer.html
---
```

Comment: I tried that by putting `footer.html` inside `www`. But I get error message `pandoc: footer.html: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted`

Comment: Don't need to put it in a `www` folder, it has to be in the same folder as the `.Rmd` file.

Comment: How about adding footer at a fixed position (just 10px above the bottom of the page) in the `.sidebar` of flexdashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tags$footer( HTML("<footer><small><b>&copy; Manoj Kumar 2021.</b></small></footer>"), align="left", style="position:absolute; bottom:0; width:95%; height:50px; color: #000000; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent; z-index: 1000;")
```